# Why is my question about defaulted methods closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655198/what-are-defaulted-methods-and-how-do-i-use-them-properly), is closed as an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823935/whats-the-point-in-defaulting-functions-in-c11).

Of course there are similarities but my question's point is (more) on "what are defaulted methods" and not like in the other question which is more of a "why use defaulted methods".

Well, I'm not asking to reopen the question (but I would appreciate it if you do). I just want a good explanation to settle the matter.

Comment: Forgetting the exact phrasing of the individual questions, is your question not answered by the content/answers of the supposed duplicate question?